# Need advice on implementing ROS2 knowledge in a hardware-based autonomous robot project for navigation and object manipulation

Tags: navigation, ros2, robotic-arm, camera, sensors

I'm new to ROS2 and looking for guidance on implementing my knowledge in a project. I've learned concepts like publisher-subscriber, services, TF, URDF, RViz, Gazebo, and Navigation2. Now, I want to build an autonomous robot capable of navigating in a map with obstacles. To achieve this, I plan to use IMU, encoders, and a camera, employing sensor fusion techniques as Lidar isn't an option. Additionally, the robot needs to identify and manipulate colored balls.

While I have a rough idea for simulation, I'm unsure about the hardware implementation, especially with my camera and sensors. I'd appreciate advice on how to approach this and any recommended resources.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's important to break down your project into manageable steps, especially when dealing with hardware and sensor fusion. Here is a high-level outline of how you can approach your project:

**1. Define Hardware Components**

- `IMU (Inertial Measurement Unit):` Choose a suitable IMU sensor for measuring orientation and acceleration, preferably one with ROS drivers available. You can also interface your IMU with a microcontroller and use rosserial.
- `Encoders:` Select encoders for wheel odometry to estimate the robot's position and movement. Alternatively, choose motors with built-in encoders. Using encoders can be tricky, so you can explore the option of visual odometry provided by the depth/stereo camera using an appropriate package.
- `Camera:` Pick a camera compatible with ROS 2, ideally one with a ROS driver available. A decent choice for a depth camera can be Intel RealSense D435i.
- `Actuators:` Decide on motors and actuators for controlling the robot's movement, depending on the weight of the robot. Motor drivers will be required to control the motors after receiving signals from the microcontroller or SBC.

**2. ROS 2 Package Setup**
Create ROS 2 packages to manage your project. Organize your code into packages, such as one for sensor drivers, one for control, one for perception, simulation, etc.

**3. Sensor Integration**
Integrate your sensors into your ROS 2 system and publish the data as standard sensor_msgs.

**4. Sensor Fusion**
Implement sensor fusion techniques to combine data from the IMU and encoders to improve localization. Consider using the `robot_localization` package in ROS 2.

**5. Camera Perception**
Cameras like Intel RealSense have ROS wrappers and can be used to publish useful data as ROS 2 topics. Implement image processing algorithms (OpenCV) to detect and track colored balls.

**6. Control**
ROS 2 control can be used to control your actuators, or you can set up your own control on the robot by writing custom code for SBC and microcontrollers attached to motor drivers.

**7. Navigation**
Use Nav2 to set up a navigation stack for your robot. You'll need a map of the environment, which can be created using SLAM packages like Cartographer, AMCL, or RTAB-Map. For depth cameras, `rtabmap_ros` will be a good choice.

**8. Testing and Debugging**
Test each component individually and then integrate them step by step. Use RViz for visualisation and debugging. It's a powerful tool for monitoring the robot's sensors, navigation, and perception.

**9. Deployment**
Once your robot works well in simulation, you can transfer your code and configurations to your physical hardware. Be prepared for debugging and fine-tuning on the real robot.

**Resources**
As for resources, consider the following:

- This [YouTube playlist](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLunhqkrRNRhYAffV8JDiFOatQXuU-NnxT&si=ZtunY69HSNQazbRy) can be a really helpful resource to build a ROS 2 hardware project from scratch.
  Remember that hardware integration can be challenging, and you may encounter compatibility issues. Be patient and persistent in troubleshooting problems. Good luck with your autonomous robot project!

Comment: Do I need to select hardware based on ROS2 compatibility and available drivers, or is it feasible to use similar hardware and develop ROS2 compatibility myself?

Comment: Better off buying compatible hardware, you'll have enough work to do regardless.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the Robotics Stack Exchange. The question that you have put forward is quite broad, and we usually prefer asking short, and concise questions on this forum. I'd invite you to take a look at [questions you should avoid asking here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

It's great that you have started to learn the initial concepts as you mentioned above. These are fundamentals which are quite important to be able to design your software in the later stages.

> Now, I want to build an autonomous robot capable of navigating in a map with obstacles

In order to get here, I'd say that you start with simulations in Gazebo. You will obtain a good degree of information about your potential blocking points when you perform extensive simulations.

> I'm unsure about the hardware implementation, especially with my camera and sensors

Usually, you would have some kind of **computer which runs the ROS stack** and does all the heavy lifting, *e.g.*, image processing from the camera, receiving feedback and sending the appropriate commands to the motor driver, and so on. Then you would have a **motor driver**, which would be able to send the appropriate voltage and current to your motors according to a certain input commands you might pass in. You might also want to have closed-loop feedback from the motor encoders in order to perform odometry calculations, in which case you would abstract the motor driver inside a **motor controller**, a higher level device which interfaces directly with your motor driver and your computer *(maybe using some serial protocol)*. Usually this motor controller is some sort of microcontroller which sits between the PC and the motor driver, and translates the serial commands into a language which the motor driver will understand *(A very common one is PWM)*.

You will find a great deal of in-depth resources to work with from [this](https://articulatedrobotics.xyz/mobile-robot-1-project-overview/) particular blog post by Josh Newans.